# Filterable row is not working in Asp.net but it is working in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui-grid

> In the below code I am getting columnheaders but I am not getting auto
>   text boxes to filter data below on every column, this attribute was
>   called in kendo grid  filterable:{ mode: "row"}, but I have added this
>   attribute in the below result was not yet come. But same code I ran in
>   MVC its working fine please help me.

```js
 grid = $("#gridAllPayers").data("kendoGrid");
    var gridHeight = $(window).height() - 220;
    var configuration = {
        columns: getheaderswithcolumns(),
        resizable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        reorderable: true,
        height: gridHeight,
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },
        navigatable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: true
        }
    };

    var Feedback = $("#gridAllPayers").kendoGrid(configuration).data("kendoGrid");

}
function getheaderswithcolumns() {
    var cols = new Array();
    cols.push(
        {
            field: "PayerName", title: "Insurance Name", headerAttributes: { "class": "table-header-cell", style: "text-align:center;font-size: 13px" },
            width: 220, attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" },
        },
        {
            field: "PayerPlan", title: "Plan Name", headerAttributes: { "class": "Test", style: "text-align: left; font-size: 13px" }, width: 220,
            attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" },
        },
        {
            field: "State", title: "Insurance's State", headerAttributes: { "class": "table-header-cell", style: "text-align: left; font-size: 13px" }, width: 200,
            attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" },
        },
        {
            field: "ClaimStatusPhoneNumber", title: "Claim Status #", headerAttributes: { "class": "table-header-cell", style: " font-size: 13px" }, width: 200,
            attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" },


        },
        {
            field: "ClaimMailingAddress", title: "Claim's Mailing Address", headerAttributes: { "class": "table-header-cell", style: "font-size: 11px" }, width: 300,

        }
      )
    return cols;
}
```

```html
<link href="kendoui/kendo.dataviz.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendoui/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendoui/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendoui/kendo.dataviz.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="content/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


    <div id="gridAllPayers">

    </div>
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` just after the `var Feedback =` line

Comment: Your attributes have an extra comma after them: `attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" },` should be `attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" }` - no comma trailing as it is the last object and some browsers do not like this.

Comment: Just on the off chance, do you have the version of the Kendo that supports the filterable.mode row? (right off I do not know when that was added) - compare the two versions to ensure that it is.

Comment: Thank you for information, but extra closing parenthesis } i have copied code incorrectly with Closing tag, but that code i have used inside the method so closing tag is must.And i removed comma from attributes: { style: "text-align:left;" }, but it bot working it showing same result.And i have checked all scripts with working scripts every thing showing matched.please help me some on this.

Answer (score 0):

I did a mock up of a page similar to the layout you describe above.  I then set the Kendo UI to a recent version and it worked as expected.  I then set it to an older version and the row filter (which was not supported) does not show.

Here is the code:

```
var griddataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        id: 1,
        PayerName: "Jane Doe",
        PayerPlan: "planer",
        State: "NE",
        ClaimStatusPhoneNumber: "1234",
        ClaimMailingAddress: "Howdy lane"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        PayerName: "Jany Doe",
        PayerPlan: "planer",
        State: "GA",
        ClaimStatusPhoneNumber: "1234345",
        ClaimMailingAddress: "123 Howdy lane"
    }

    ],
    batch: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                "id": {
                    editable: false,
                    nullable: true
                },
                    "PayerName": {
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: false
                },
                    "PayerPlan": {
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: true
                },
                    "State": {
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: true
                },
                    "ClaimStatusPhoneNumber": {
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: true
                },
                    "ClaimMailingAddress": {
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: true
                }
            }

        }
    }
});
//var grid = $("#gridAllPayers").data("kendoGrid");
var gridHeight = 330; // $(window).height() - 220;
var configuration = {
    columns: getheaderswithcolumns(),
   // resizable: true,
   // columnMenu: true,
  //  reorderable: true,
   // height: gridHeight,
    //filterable: true,
    filterable: {
                mode: "menu, row"
     },
    dataSource: griddataSource,
   // navigatable: true,
   // sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: true
    }
};

var Feedback = $("#gridAllPayers").kendoGrid(configuration).data("kendoGrid");
griddataSource.insert(3, {
    id: 3,
    PayerName: "John Doe",
    PayerPlan: "planer",
    State: "NE",
    ClaimStatusPhoneNumber: "1234",
    ClaimMailingAddress: "Howdy lane"
});
griddataSource.insert(4, {
    id: 4,
    PayerName: "Jackne Doe",
    PayerPlan: "planer",
    State: "NE",
    ClaimStatusPhoneNumber: "1234",
    ClaimMailingAddress: "Howdy lane"
});
Feedback.refresh();


function getheaderswithcolumns() {
    var cols = [];
    cols.push({
        field: "PayerName",
        title: "Insurance Name",
        headerAttributes: {
            "class": "table-header-cell",
            style: "text-align:center;font-size: 13px"
        },
        width: 220,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align:left;"
        },
        filterable: {
            cell: {
                showOperators: false
            }
        }
    }, {
        field: "PayerPlan",
        title: "Plan Name",
        headerAttributes: {
            "class": "Test",
            style: "text-align: left; font-size: 13px"
        },
        width: 220,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align:left;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "State",
        title: "Insurance's State",
        headerAttributes: {
            "class": "table-header-cell",
            style: "text-align: left; font-size: 13px"
        },
        width: 200,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align:left;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ClaimStatusPhoneNumber",
        title: "Claim Status #",
        headerAttributes: {
            "class": "table-header-cell",
            style: " font-size: 13px"
        },
        width: 200,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align:left;"
        }
    }, {
        field: "ClaimMailingAddress",
        title: "Claim's Mailing Address",
        headerAttributes: {
            "class": "table-header-cell",
            style: "font-size: 11px"
        },
        width: 300
    });
    return cols;
}
```

See working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/zLm35vfe

And then the older version where it does not work:  http://jsfiddle.net/zLm35vfe/1/

Note that this older (not supported) version uses the CDN as described here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/cdn

That contains the specific version of https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js

Comment: Thank you for your great help 'Mark Schultheiss',Now i changed old version to new, Now its working fine.